# How do yo move a UIWebView offscreen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiwebview

How do you move a `UIWebView` offscreen?

Is that determined by the `CGRect`? Or some other property of `UIView` or `UIWindow`?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
[webView setFrame:CGRectMake(320.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
```

or

```
[webView removeFromSuperview];
```

The first one just move it offscreen, you just cannot see it. The second one remove it from `superview`, maybe it still exist in memory, or maybe it'll removed when received memory warning.

Answer (score 1):

`UIWebView` is a subclass of `UIView` (as are most visible objects in cocoa touch) which means you can use `setBounds` or `setFrame` in order to 'move' the view. If you use negative or large positive numbers the view will be moved offscreen.

Do remember that things offscreen also take up memory ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. You could change the `frame` property of `UIWebView` to some coordinates which are off the screen.

You could do this but if you are done with the `UIWebView` & simply want to close it then this might not be the best solution as the memory allocated is still not released. First animate it off the screen then release it to free the memory. To release it do `[YourWebView removeFromSuperview]; [YourWebView release]; YourWebView=nil;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it by setting the hidden property to `YES`.

You can also move it off the screen with the frame, as you mentioned. A good place to start is `CGRectMake(self.superview.frame.size.width,self.superview.frame.size.height,...)` though it won't do well with rotations.

You can also set the alpha to 0, which is akin to making it hidden.

You can also send it the method `removeFromSuperview`.

There may be more ways.

Enjoy,

Damien